# webpack dev server change root

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

How can i serve webpack dev server from a subdirectory (change the root where the server is running) . Now my server is available on http://localhost and i want it to run on http://localhost/site. I want both files under ./dist and the bundles to be available from http://localhost/site.

```
return new webpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: './dist',
  hot: true,
  publicPath: '/site/',
  proxy: {
    '/backend': {
      secure: false,
      target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/backend': ''
      }
    }
  }
}).listen(80);
```

I tried with publicPath but that doesn't seem to work. Is that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the root, you have to add the following configuration to your webpack's configuration

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/site/'
  }
};
```

This would allow you to serve your files under that specific path.

More info:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-publicpath-

Comment: I believe setting `contentBase` would be the right way to do it.